# NSFetchedResultsController pushes updates without having pushed any inserts

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a NSFetchedResultsController initialized like so:

```
  lazy var postsResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController = {
    // Initialize Fetch Request
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Post")

    // Add Sort Descriptors
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "owner == %@" , "owner",self.user)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    // Initialize Fetched Results Controller
    let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: StateControl.managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

    // Configure Fetched Results Controller
    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self

    return fetchedResultsController
  }()
```

and I set my controller as the delegate. Here is an overview of the delegate methods:

```
  func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    NSLog("Begin updates")
    userPosts.beginUpdates()
  }

  func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    NSLog("End updates")
    userPosts.endUpdates()
  }

  func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {

    switch (type) {
    case .Insert:
      if let indexPath = newIndexPath {
        userPosts.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Left)
      }
    case .Delete:
      if let indexPath = indexPath {
        userPosts.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Left)
      }
    case .Update:
      print("Update request")
      if let indexPath = indexPath {
        userPosts.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
      }
    case .Move:
      if let indexPath = indexPath {
        userPosts.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
      }

      if let newIndexPath = newIndexPath {
        userPosts.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
      }
    }
  }
```

And below you see my `UITableViewDataSource` delegate methods:

```
  func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return postsResultsController.sections?.count ?? 0
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if let sections = postsResultsController.sections {
      let sectionInfo = sections[section]
      return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects
    }
    else {return 0}
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let post = postsResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Post
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(ReuseIdentifiers.PostCollectionViewCell, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PostCell
    cell.setup(withPost: post, fromUser: user)
    return cell
  }
```

I set myself as the delegate in my tableView's `didSet`:

```
var userPosts: PostsTableView! {
    didSet {
      userPosts.delegate = self
      userPosts.dataSource = self
      userPosts.scrollEnabled = false
    }
  }
```

However, when I arrive to `viewDidLoad:`, I do the following:

```
do {
  try self.postsResultsController.performFetch()
} catch {
  let fetchError = error as NSError
  print("\(fetchError), \(fetchError.userInfo)")
}
userPosts.reloadData()
```

And yet, my tableView remains completely empty. What I have noticed is that my log shows that userPostsController is pushing update requests but no inserts.

```
2016-02-29 15:31:52.073 Columize[10373:149421] Begin updates
Update request
2016-02-29 15:31:52.073 Columize[10373:149421] End updates
2016-02-29 15:31:52.074 Columize[10373:149421] Begin updates
Update request
2016-02-29 15:31:52.074 Columize[10373:149421] End updates
```

So, my best guess is that the NSFetchedResultsController just watches the context and passes on updates (I do a lot of fetching from backend that merge with existing objects, hence the many updates), but it was my understanding that every time I create a new NSFecthedResultsController it would populate and pass on the appropriate delegate calls (mainly inserts).

Furthermore, I'm assuming that means that after a `NSManagedObjectContext` has interacted with a `NSFecthedResultsController`, subsequent `NSFecthedResultsController`s simply don't push Inserts.

1-Is my reasoning correct?
2-How can I circumvent that? Do I have to create a new context for every `NSFecthedResultsController`?

**UPDATE**

So the reason nothing was showing was because my tableView had height of zero (wooops). However nothing will appear if I don't call `reloadData` after the first fetch, so my question stands, namely, **why aren't there any inserts performed by my `NSFetchedResultsController`**?

Comment: I think you just need to reloadData on the table after the first fetch in the view did load.

Comment: Have you hooked up the table view's data source property to your VC? Sorry about the first comment - I didn't see it in the do block.

Comment: Yes, I do that in the didSet: Observer of my tableView. I updated my answer to show you.

Comment: What concurrency type is the context for the FRC?  Are your backend updates made directly in the same context?  If not, how are the two contexts related?

Comment: The FRC watches the MOC, the one initialized in my App Delegate. The updates are made in a private context whose parent is the MOC.

Comment: The FRC does not generate delegate calls for the objects in the initial `performFetch`.  Hence the need to `reloadData`.  Are you getting the delegate calls for subsequent inserts?

Comment: Yes, subsequent inserts work fine. I understand now, it's a bit of a disappointment, everything works perfectly after. I just thought FRC was a little different that it actually is!